# Can you rent a bicycle in a city and return it in another one in France?

Tags: france, rental, bicycles

I'm planning a bicycle trip from the city of Selestat to Mulhouse.

Is there a place where you can rent a bike in one of the cities and return it in the other one?

This question is apparently very specific to these cities, but it's in fact more general: can you do that in some other pair of cities in France? Is it common?

Comment: There are some options for 'one way' bicycle renting, for example on the atlantic coast : https://www.lavelodyssee.com/conseil/organisez-votre-voyage/transport-des-velos-et-des-bagages but I couldn't find options for your itinerary.

Comment: An alternative might be to rent the bicycle in Mulhouse, go to Selestat by train with the bicycle (most TER trains have space for bicycles) and cycle back to Mulhouse.

Answer (score 2):

France has an excellent cycling trail network and facilities. In regions that have popular bike trails there are usually small localized companies that allow you to do one way bike rentals.

[Freewheelingfrance](http://www.freewheelingfrance.com/bike-hire-in-france/) is a website that contains a list of rental agencies and tips around cycling in France.

[The Alsace](http://www.cyclinginalsace.com), the region asked about in the question is very popular for it's wine and vineyard cycling trail. So there will be plenty of bike hire places in the area. I don't know about the specific locations asked about, but I would expect many agencies will offer one way rentals along the route. As with hire cars, one way rentals usually incur an additional fee.

Comment: Are bike rental places in those regions typically chains? It wouldn't do much good to go into a rental shop and ask for a one-way to a place where that particular shop doesn't have a sister office to return the bike to.

Comment: Some rental companies have mulitiple outlets, others have partner locations such as hotels and some even over delivery and pickup services. I came accross all these options while I was researching my cycling trip in the Loire vally last summer.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better buy a second hand (VTT) bike and enjoy as much as you like...it will be cheaper than renting one if your ride takes several days. Check it out. Most 2nd hand VTT stores give you good deals even may hint where to return it to resell it in the other city.